# CSS- Transition not working

Tags: html, css, transition

Hello everyone I'm currently trying to do a transition when you hover the background turns purple and the text-color turns white.(originally there's no background color and the text-color is black...)

But it ain't working!

What is it that Im doing wrong!?

```
a:hover {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 1000ms linear;
    transition: color 1000ms linear;
    background-color: purple;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

So///EDIT as everyone keeps telling me to add it on a instead of a:hover...

Initial state:

```
text-color:black;
background:none;
```

Hovered state:

Smooth Transition to:

```
 text-color:white;
background:black;
```

I hope this helps everyone out
Thanks for your time!

Comment: It appears to be working here. http://jsfiddle.net/4zhnP/ ... did you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pySY4/

Comment: It would be easier if you included some html. You might need to do something like `.header > .navlinks > li > a:hover`

Comment: @JoshC yeah something like that but smoother!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put them on the a (not the hover) AND if you want multiple transitions you have to declare them together.

```
-webkit-transition: color 1000ms linear, background-color 1000ms linear;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zhnP/1/

Comment: Thank you, your description and your solution provided clear,concise information on why and how to do it.

:D

Answer (score 5):

Don't set the transition on the :hover property.

```
a {
color: white;
-webkit-transition: color 1000ms linear;
-moz-transition: color 1000ms linear;
-o-transition: color 1000ms linear;
-ms-transition: color 1000ms linear;
transition: color 1000ms linear;
background-color: purple;
-webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
-o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

Then set what is actually changing on the `:hover` property.
For example,

```
a:hover{
color:green;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so If I wanted initially the text-color to be black, and no background and once you hover the transition begins to background color purple and text-color white how would be?

Comment: @user2766367 You would have something like this:

`a:hover{background:purple;color:white;}`

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the transitions on the `a`, instead of the `a:hover`.

You can find more information on transitions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Why would you recommend that?